# Silverlight website isn't working in Domain Environment

Tags: silverlight, dns, active-directory, workgroup

I am running Server 2003 and client as Windows 7. I am trying to log-in to a website ( openjet.damanhealth.ae ). If my PC is running as Workgroup, I can log-in to the website and everything works normal. But when I join domain, the same website doesn't allow me to log-in and the error message appears as "User credentials are invalid". It looks like the website is failed in some authentication process. Even after dis-joining the same PC from domain, back to Workgroup, I am still unable to log-in.

Do I need to make some settings in the Group Policies? Right now I am running the Server with all default policies. No extra settings done in GP. What can be the changes Server has made in the client PC to stop working?